# Doxygen: Creating a specialised page

Tags: doxygen, deprecated

I finally figured out how to use deprecated to mark functions as going away. What I'd like to generate is an additional page listed on "Related Pages" (much like GENERATE_DEPRECATED does) that allows me to list APIs that have changed.

If we pull a function say
doFoo(int,SOMECLASS)

in place of
doFoo(uInt_64, SOMECLASS, &errInstance)

What I'd like is a way to have a page that I can put

**Changed:**

```
doFoo(int, SOMECLASS) removed: Use doFoo(uInt, SOMECLASS, &errInstance)
```

To make matters worse; I'm not sure how to do this without actually reenabling the old call in the header despite the fact that  it's now been removed.

Suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the \xrefitem command in combination with an ALIAS definition if you want to define your own command (such as \change) that behaves like \deprecated.

See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem for more info.

Answer (score 0):

For stuff like that, I create a file that is one big comment with text and code blocks:

```
/*! 
\page changed Changed

<b>Changed:</b>

/code
doFoo(int, SOMECLASS) removed: Use doFoo(uInt, SOMECLASS, &errInstance)
/endcode

*/
```

Comment: Don't you have to include that file in the INPUT? If then, wouldn't it show up in the File List, which is not desirable?

Comment: That may be. I don't show the file list; so, it's not a problem for me. I guess you could tack that page on the bottom of an existing file.

Comment: I see. I guess this is where Doxygen can do better.

Comment: Yes. I find Doxygen both brilliant and frustrating at the same time.

Comment: Doxygen doesn't show the file in the File List if the extension is either .doc, .dox, or .txt.